# Find coefficient of $x^3y^4z^5$ in polynomial $(x + y + z)^8(x + y + z + 1)^8$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Find coefficient of $x^3y^4z^5$ in polynomial $(x + y + z)^8(x + y + z + 1)^8$

It is pretty easy to see that our goal is to choose from each multiplier in this polynomial $x,y,z,1$ in certain amounts. Since sum of powers equals $12$ and we have $16$ multipliers, we have to choose four $1$'s. There are $\displaystyle {8 \choose 4}$ ways to choose $1$ as part of our product (actually, four $1$'s). But how do we handle what has left? It seems like in such solution we have to consider many cases.

Comment: do you know mulrinomial theorem

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Probably no. At least I have never heard such name before.

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20multinomial%20theorem,theorem%20from%20binomials%20to%20multinomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pick 3 $x$'s, 4 $y$'s, and 5 $z$'s from the remaining 12 'multipliers', so you are now literally picking which multiplier you want for each variable. Hence there are
$$\binom{12}{3}\binom{12-3}{4}\binom{12-3-4}{5}$$
ways to do so

$\textbf{Side note}$: the expression here are often written as
$$\binom{12}{3,4,5}=\frac{12!}{3!4!5!}$$
as a multinomial coefficient. The order 3,4,5 does not matter (for a simple proof, write the binomial coefs in terms of factorials, and things will cancel out nicely)

Comment: So, you assumed that we have already chosen 1's, right?

Comment: Yes. Once the 1's are chosen, we choose 3 multipliers for $x$, then 4 multipliers for $y$, and the remaining for $z$. Again, the order of variables being chosen does not matter (which make sense, intuitively and mathematically)

Comment: This is not correct answer. It is multiplication of two multinomials!

Comment: @MathLover is right at pointing that out, see [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+%7Bx%5E3+y%5E4+z%5E5%7D+in+%28x%2By%2Bz%29%5E8+*+%28x%2By%2Bz%2B1%29%5E8) as well

Comment: Yes, this is not the final coefficient. I'm just giving him to way to 'handle what has left' as asked

Answer (score 4):

Objective: To find coefficient of $\ x^3y^4z^5\ $ in $\ (x + y + z)^8(x + y + z + 1)^8$

First expand $$(1+(x+y+z))^8=\sum_{r=0}^{8} {8 \choose r}(x+y+z)^r$$
Now multiplying $(1+(x+y+z))^8$ with $(x+y+z)^8$ gives us,

$$(x+y+z)^8(1+(x+y+z))^8=\sum_{r=0}^{8} {8 \choose r}(x+y+z)^{r+8} \label{1} \tag{1}$$

Now using multinomial theorem, coefficient of $x^3y^4z^5$ in $(x+y+z)^n$ is $\Large{}{n \choose {3,\ 4,\ 5}}$ only when $n=12$.

Applying the same logic on equation $(1)$, we get the coefficient as

$$\sum_{r=0}^{8} {8 \choose r}* {8+r \choose {3,\ 4,\ 5}}$$ so we can fix $r=4$ and the answer we get is $${8\choose4}*{12\choose{3,4,5}}$$

For computationally rigorous answer see [Wolfram Alpha coefficient finder](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+%7Bx%5E3+y%5E4+z%5E5%7D+in+%28x%2By%2Bz%29%5E8+*+%28x%2By%2Bz%2B1%29%5E8)